Exporting a Mathematica graphics as an editable eps
I want to export a Mathematica graph as an eps file and then edit parts of it in Illustrator. For instance, I want to be able to adjust line weights or colors of the graph of a function. I know I've done this in the past but it's been a few years and I suspect there's been some changes to either or both programs. I am able to save a graph as an eps file but when I open the file in Illustrator, it opens as a single graphic object so I'm not able to edit it.

Does Export["filename", graphics] not work?

This works to create an eps file with the graph. The problem is that the eps file contains a single graphics object so I am not able to edit the pieces of the graph in Illustrator.

Why not using PDF format? It is almost native for AI.

Same issue with pdf's. I think I know the problem. I've been trying to create a graphic containing the shaded region corresponding to the solution of two linear inequalities using the RegionPlot command. Apparently the graph that Mathematica creates contains just a single graphics object.

@Daniel Huber A few years ago there were problems in exporting graphics as eps. Namely, Phys. Rev. did not accept such files. Did I miss something since then?

One way to combine with Illustrator is to copy the graphic in Mathematica and paste into Illustrator. The resulting object is fully editable.

"single graphical object.." But is it possible to double-click it to enter inside? I do not have AI on my laptop, but I remember it was possible.
